# How to delete a Backup from a backup set in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008-r2, disk-space

The title pretty much sums it up. We are running out of space on our backup disks, and need to remove old backups out of the set. I can't seem to find any information on this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would change your backup strategy to write to individual files for each database backup.  You could then have a maintenance plan step that examines your backup location and removes *.bak files older the X days.

Comment: Agree 100% - write your backups as individual files. Use maintenance plans or Ola Hallengren's excellent scripts.

Comment: We ended up doing this, just stinks that we have to have a maintenance plan, and that the backupset can't handle that.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way (that I've ever heard of) to delete a single backup from a backup file.  This is why people write each backup to a separate file so you can just delete the old files.

Comment: Do you know if anything changed from 2011? I've spent a lot of time searching for a way to delete individual backups from a file.

Comment: Nope nothing has changed and I'd expect nothing to ever change on that front. In fact new features like backup to url only support one backup per file.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you really want to get a db with those selected items you could restore the database to a new database and choose the backups you want to keep whilst restoring.